# How to add right uptime on my powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell

Hi I'm sorry if my grammar is so bad, so i have a powershell script that show utilization on the server and dont know how to add uptime value in my code , because it's my first time to use powershell. Here is my code:

```bsh
$ServerListFile = "C:\utilization\ServerList.txt"
$ServerList = Get-Content $ServerListFile -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue  
$Result = @()  
ForEach ($computername in $ServerList) { 
 
    $AVGProc = Get-WmiObject -computername $computername win32_processor |  
    Measure-Object -property LoadPercentage -Average | Select Average 
    $OS = gwmi -Class win32_operatingsystem -computername $computername | 
    Select-Object @{Name = "MemoryUsage"; Expression = { “{0:N2}” -f ((($_.TotalVisibleMemorySize - $_.FreePhysicalMemory)*100)/ $_.TotalVisibleMemorySize) } } 
    $vol = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_Volume -ComputerName $computername -Filter "DriveLetter = 'C:'" | 
    Select-object @{Name = "C PercentFree"; Expression = { “{0:N2}” -f (($_.FreeSpace / $_.Capacity)*100) } } 
    $uptime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | 
    Select-Object LastBootUpTime  

   
    $result += [PSCustomObject] @{  
        ServerName = "$computername" 
        CPULoad    = "$($AVGProc.Average)%" 
        MemLoad    = "$($OS.MemoryUsage)%" 
        CDrive     = "$($vol.'C PercentFree')%"
        uptime     = "$uptime"
    } 
 
    $Outputreport = "<HTML><TITLE> Server Health Report </TITLE> 
                     <BODY background-color:peachpuff> 
                     <font color =""#99000"" face=""Microsoft Tai le""> 
                     <H2> Server Health Report </H2></font> 
                     <Table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0> 
                     <TR bgcolor=gray align=center> 
                       <TD><B>Server Name</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Avrg.CPU Utilization</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>Memory Utilization</B></TD> 
                       <TD><B>C Drive Utilizatoin</B></TD>
               <TD><B>Uptime Utilization</B></TD></TR>" 
                         
    Foreach ($Entry in $Result)  
    {  
        if ((($Entry.CpuLoad) -or ($Entry.memload)) -ge "80") {  
            $Outputreport += "<TR bgcolor=red>"  
        }  
        else { 
            $Outputreport += "<TR>"  
        } 
        $Outputreport += "<TD>$($Entry.Servername)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.CPULoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.MemLoad)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.Cdrive)</TD><TD align=center>$($Entry.uptime)</TD></TR>"  
    } 
    $Outputreport += "</Table></BODY></HTML>"  
}  
  
$Outputreport | out-file C:\utilization\report\report.htm  
Invoke-Expression C:\utilization\report\report.htm  
##Send email functionality from below line, use it if you want    
#$smtpServer = "yoursmtpserver.com" 
#$smtpFrom = "fromemailaddress@test.com" 
#$smtpTo = "receipentaddress@test.com" 
#$messageSubject = "Servers Health report" 
#$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $smtpfrom, $smtpto 
#$message.Subject = $messageSubject 
#$message.IsBodyHTML = $true 
#$message.Body = "<head><pre>$style</pre></head>" 
#$message.Body += Get-Content C:\pathhtml
#$smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer) 
#$smtp.Send($message)
```

And the ouput is like this:

[image]

so how to solve the uptime output on my script?

Comment: In your ps1 file change `$uptime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object @{LABEL='LastBootUpTime';EXPRESSION={$_.ConverttoDateTime($_.lastbootuptime)}}.LastBootUpTime`

Comment: @VivekKumarSingh it's doesnt work bro , here is the output https://imgur.com/a/ULqfjDv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the following:

```
$uptime = Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem | Select-Object LastBootUpTime
```

To:

```
$uptime = ((Get-date) - [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime(((Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).LastBootUpTime))).tostring()
```

This will display similar to:

```
40.10:23:40.2993561
```

This shows 40 Days, 10 hours, 23 minutes and 40 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following snippet for your `$uptime` variable

```
(New-TimeSpan -Start (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property LastBootUpTime).LastBootUpTime -End (Get-Date)).ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Get-CimInstance` to fetch the LastBootUpTime, you will get a valid DateTime object in local time. Using WMI, you need to convert the (string) timestamp into a DateTime object before you can work with it.

In a report, I would probably want to show the uptime duration in the `Uptime Utilization` column as formatted string like `5 days 6 hours 5 minutes 53 seconds`

For that, you can do:

```
# subtract the LastBootUpTime date from the current date and time to get a TimeSpan object
$ts = (Get-Date) - (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computername).LastBootUpTime
# now format it into a human readable string to go in the report
$uptime = '{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds' -f $ts.Days, $ts.Hours, $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds
```

---

If you do want to keep using `Get-WmiObject` instead of `Get-CimInstance`, I would add a small helper function on top of the script:

```
function Get-UptimeDuration ([string]$WmiTimeStamp) {
    $date = ([wmi]"").ConvertToDateTime($WmiTimeStamp)
    # or use:
    #$date = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($WmiTimeStamp)

    # the above returns a localized date where .Kind property is 'Unspecified'. 
    $date = [DateTime]::new($date.Ticks, 'Local')  # set the DateTime Kind to 'Local'
    # subtract that date from the current date and time to get a TimeSpan object
    $ts = (Get-Date) - $date
    # now output a formatted duration string to go in the report
    '{0} days {1} hours {2} minutes {3} seconds' -f $ts.Days, $ts.Hours, $ts.Minutes, $ts.Seconds
}
```

and use it like this :

```
$uptime = Get-UptimeDuration (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $computername).LastBootUpTime
```

<sup>P.S. You forgot parameter `-ComputerName $computername` for the part where you get the LastBootUpTime property.</sup>

Comment: what is the diffrent between Get-WmiObject and Get-CimInstance

Comment: @sudo3rs Quite a lot really, see [here](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/should-i-use-cim-or-wmi-with-windows-powershell/%23:~:text%3DThe%2520big%2520difference%2520between%2520the,Get%252DCimSession&ved=2ahUKEwi_ntXzsrnrAhWRy6QKHdsSAQ4QFjABegQICxAG&usg=AOvVaw0tfEXM4Otvx6OeBC2Gc-QX)